# Create this state using CIRQ Coding language

Tags: quantum-state, programming, mathematics, cirq

I needed help with CIRQ coding as I'm quite new to Quantum Computing.
I read the tutorials on CIRQ but don't really understand it.
I'd be very thankful if someone could help.

A program to create the state using CIRQ coding.

A program to create the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on what specifically about the tutorial you don't understand?

Answer (score 3):

The state you want to create is called a Bell State. Creating it can be accomplished [by a Hadamard gate followed by a CNOT gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state#Creating_Bell_states) . In Cirq this will be

```
q0 = cirq.GridQubit(0, 0)
q1 = cirq.GridQubit(0, 1)

circuit = cirq.Circuit(
    cirq.H(q0),
    cirq.CNOT(q0, q1)
    
)
```

Printing the circuit show's that this is indeed the case.

```
print(circuit)

# Circuit:
# (0, 0): ───H───@───
#                │
# (0, 1): ───────X───
```